# react native ToastAndroid in ios

Tags: react-native

I have created several android apps by using react native, I always and like to use ToastAndroid because it can pop up message and app user don't have to close it by clicking screen. Now I want to create IOS version from my apps. I want to ask what is your alternatives for android toast in ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-root-toast](https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-root-toast) to make a Toast for both android and iOS.

Comment: brilliant answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend [react-native-customizable-toast](https://github.com/kubilaysalih/react-native-customizable-toast). It's updated and works with android,ios and expo